# Add hyperlink to Python Plotly Sunburst diagram

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, hyperlink, plotly

If possible, I need to add hyperlinks to a Plotly Sunburst chart so that a user can click and go to a webpage with more information.

[Sunburst chart showing where hyperlinks are needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B909M.png)

[I've tried organizing the data two different ways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMGIH.png)

Here's the data in coffeeURL.csv:

```
ids,labels,parents
Enzymatic-Flowery,Flowery,
Enzymatic-Fruity,Fruity,
Enzymatic-Herby,Herby,
<a href=Flower-Floral.html>Flowery-Floral</a>,Floral,Enzymatic-Flowery
<a href=Flower-Fragrant.html>Flowery-Fragrant</a>,Fragrant,Enzymatic-Flowery
<a href=Fruity-Citrus.html>Fruity-Citrus</a>,Citrus,Enzymatic-Fruity
<a href=Fruity-Berry-like.html>Fruity-Berry-like</a>,Berry-like,Enzymatic-Fruity
<a href=Herby-Alliaceous.html>Herby-Alliaceous</a>,Alliaceous,Enzymatic-Herby
<a href=Herby-Leguminous.html>Herby-Leguminous</a>,Leguminous,Enzymatic-Herby
```

Here's the script:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('coffeeURL.csv')

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Sunburst(
    ids=df.ids,
    labels=df.labels,
    parents=df.parents,
    domain=dict(column=1),
    maxdepth=2,
    insidetextorientation='radial'
))

fig.update_layout(
    margin = dict(t=10, l=10, r=10, b=10)
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: This link maybe useful for you.https://community.plotly.com/t/is-it-possible-to-add-a-hyperlink-to-data-points-in-a-scatter-plot/28343/5

Answer (score 0):

- you can achieve this is you use **dash** and a **callback**
- your URLs are not accessible to me so have used results of a Google search with results going into an **Iframe**

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ids,labels,parents
Enzymatic-Flowery,Flowery,
Enzymatic-Fruity,Fruity,
Enzymatic-Herby,Herby,
<a href=Flower-Floral.html>Flowery-Floral</a>,Floral,Enzymatic-Flowery
<a href=Flower-Fragrant.html>Flowery-Fragrant</a>,Fragrant,Enzymatic-Flowery
<a href=Fruity-Citrus.html>Fruity-Citrus</a>,Citrus,Enzymatic-Fruity
<a href=Fruity-Berry-like.html>Fruity-Berry-like</a>,Berry-like,Enzymatic-Fruity
<a href=Herby-Alliaceous.html>Herby-Alliaceous</a>,Alliaceous,Enzymatic-Herby
<a href=Herby-Leguminous.html>Herby-Leguminous</a>,Leguminous,Enzymatic-Herby"""))

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Sunburst(
    ids=df.ids,
    labels=df.labels,
    parents=df.parents,
    domain=dict(column=1),
    maxdepth=2,
    insidetextorientation='radial'
))

fig.update_layout(
    margin = dict(t=10, l=10, r=10, b=10)
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(
            id="figure",
            figure=fig,
        ),
        html.Iframe(
            id="details",
            src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&ei=&q=flowers",
            style={"height": "1067px", "width": "100%"},
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("details", "src"), [Input("figure", "clickData")])
def clickPoint(clickData):
    if clickData:
        try:
            clicked_id = clickData["points"][0]["id"]
            clicked_id = clicked_id.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
            return f"https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&ei=&q={clicked_id}"
        except IndexError:
            raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate


app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: This is great information.  I can use this in the future.  Unfortunately, Dash and JupyterDask are not supported in the environment where I need to publish this sunburst.  I clarified with my client and we don't need the animation.  I think an SVG with links will work.  I'm working on that.